# SSH deploy from Bitbucket. Disable passphrase?

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

So basically my setup is that i'm creating an ssh pair on my remote server, then copying the pub key to bitbucket, and my server's authorized_keys file.

I'm still getting permission denied when I run my deploy on Bitbucket.

> Any SSH key you use in Pipelines should not have a passphrase.

I'm assuming this has something to do with it, even tho i created the ssh pair with a blank password, my `sshd_config` file has:

```
# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

Should I change this to yes?

Bitbucket's [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html) says I should `ssh-copy-id -i my_ssh_key user@host`, but that doesn't make sense to me since all ssh gen is either happening on the remote or in Bitbucket itself.

Have no idea why this isn't clearer.

Edit: here's the error on the bitbucket build:

```
+ cat ./deploy.sh | ssh username@remote.com
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address ‘XXX.XXX.XX.XX’ to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Here are some values of my `sshd_config`:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Have you added your host to the known hosts? Under the ssh keys?

Comment: Yes, I tried `ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` but I still get the same error. Why does Bitbucket suggest you create the pair on their servers? Aren't you trying to ssh into your remote, not vice versa?

Comment: You can add them yourself, but bitbucket needs to know/accept the fingerprint of your host. Therfore you must also have this setup in the ssh section of your repo

Comment: @SvenHakvoort What setup? Meaning the private key and pub key configured in your bitbucket? I have that already with the host added. So still not sure why its not working.

Comment: Hmm allrightm that is indeed what i meant. Can you provide the full error / stacktrace + command?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort See edit

Comment: What do the lines for `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `AuthorizedKeysFile` say in your `sshd_config`?

Comment: See edit, i'll try uncommenting the authorized keys file

Comment: You do not mention that you copied the private key to bitbucket, did you skip that step?

Comment: Yes, the private key is in bitbucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. For some reason, i had my ssh logic backwards. I re-created the ssh key pair in Bitbucket, added the public key to my remote server's `~/ssh/authorized_keys` file, AND ... I assured that the permissions of that file was set to `600`. Once I fixed that permission, I had my first successful build. Hope this helps someone.